# Missing reference / exe not working / - PowerPacks -

Tags: c#, reference, release, filenotfoundexception, powerpacks

It took 2 days of searching to solve this problem. There are many threads out there but no real solution. The most peoples are just talking about the theoretical way but not about the practical.

**Here is the problem:**

When drawing shapes or lines out of the code (without using the toolbox) the application probably wont work on other computers without further attention to the references. An error will show up "filenotfoundexception" on computers which havnt got visual studio. The point is visual studio is using *PowerPacks* which isnt showing up in the reference-list.

Searching for the missing dll around the web is pretty useless. I really tried hard without success.

---

Ill answer this question myself just for documenting this issue.
I hope this isnt against the rules. Its just about: So many people out there got this problem and no one got a solution.

**This question will get closed in 2 days!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The credit for this solution goes to: [VisualBasic PowerPack missing from Visual Studio 2013?](http://ntcoder.com/bab/2013/12/20/visualbasic-powerpack-missing-from-visual-studio-2013/)
**This is made by copy&paste.**

The way this one goes is getting visualStudio to show up the PowerPacks-reference in the project-explorer. If you got there, you can set "copy local" to true. That way you'll get the dll-file with your exe.

Download PowerPacks: [PowerPacks2013](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=321343)

1. Open Visual Studio 2013
2. Open the toolbox. Add a new tab, right click on the toolbox, select “Add Tab”. Name the tab to “Visual Basic PowerPack”.
3. Expand the new “Tab”. Right click in the empty space under the new tab and select “Choose Item”. You’ll see the following dialog popup…
4. Please give it few minutes to load all items. Please select “.Net Framework Components” tab if its not already selected.
5. In the filter text box control please type in “Power”. You should see something like this in the above dialog…
6. Check the needed PowerPack-reference (lineshape/ovalshape...) and click ok.

After this is done, PowerPacks will show up in the reference-list in the project-explorer. The property "copy local" should be checked in default.

Thats it. If u release or debug your app the dll will be copied into the folder next to your exe. Problem fixed.

I hope this documentation will help some of the guys out there.

Comment: Happy to see this is helpful.